# In C, how can you check if a bit is set using XOR?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I got this question asked at in interview.
Supposing I have to check bit 3 for:

```
 a=0x9004;
```

I said that

```
 if((a<<13>>15)^1==1)
     printf("bit 3 is not set");
 else
     printf("bit 3 is set");
```

But I'm feeling that this is not what they were looking for.

Comment: For clarity and readability use parenthesis.

Comment: A rather silly question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ((unsigned int )a ^ (0x4) < (unsigned int )a) 
    printf("bit 3 is set");
else
    printf("bit 3 is not set");
```

If bit 3 (`0x4`) was set then `a ^ 0x4` will be smaller arithmetic value then `a`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if((a | (1<<2)) ^ a)
   printf("3rd bit is not set");
else printf("3rd bit is set");
```

Answer (score 2):

as requested only Using XOR. bit count starts from 0 to bit 31.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//assuming you count from bit 0, bit 1,bit 2 up to bit 31..
int main(void){

int a = 0x7FFFFFFF;
int check = (1<<3);
check = (a - (check^a) )>0 ? 1:0;
printf("bit 3 of %x is set to %d",a,check);
return 0;
}
```